# converting data from geometric LS mean and confidence intervals to mean and SD

Tags: confidence-interval, mean, standard-deviation, geometric-mean

I Hope this letter finds you well. I am conducting a meta-analysis, and some of the studies have reported data in geometric least squares mean and confidence intervals, while others have presented data in mean and SD.

My first question is how to address such disparate data, as far as I know that we cannot combine them in a single meta-analysis.

For my second question, I am seeking guidance on the process of converting data from geometric LS mean and confidence intervals to mean and SD.

If there is an excel file where I can implant these data or any other way that you recommend.

Your expertise and insights on these matters would be Hugely valuable to my research and I would be sincerely grateful for your guidance.

Thank you all for your time and consideration

Best regards;

Comment: Sorry, for not explaining it, it simply mean geometric Least Square mean

Comment: I've edited to use the longer form on first use.